# Properties from file for java application in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to run a java class in eclipse with vm arguments.
Is there a way I can tell the properties file from where these arguments can be picked up.

Comment: VM arguments pass at run time in eclipse. So what you want exactly?

Comment: Are you sure you don't just want to use a normal *program* argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to provide eclipse the properties file of vm arguments.

But if you want to run a java class in eclipse with vm arguments, you can set those vm arguments under arguments tab (in **VM arguments** text box) in runtime configurations of your project in eclipse.

[image]